# my footer isnt coming up as being styled but using html and css

Tags: html, css

I have made HTML and CSS files to make a website for college

- Both files contained in same folder
- saved with .html and .css

the css code on the other tab is:

```
footer{ 
    width: 100%; 
    background-color:  000066; 
    padding: 60px 0px; 
}
```

So I just want to style my footer, for now

Does anyone know the reason this is happening as I've tried a few different combinations?? Thanks, everyone in advance

Image of HTML:

[image: image of html]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="wrapper">
...
</div> <!-- please close div wrapper class tag -->
```

you have wrapped the ul tag with div class but at the end the div tag is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

Close the `div` element inside the footer with class of wrapper.